# The Voice That Beckons

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, acrostic

> Lethargic apprentices nesting dreary offices 
>   Foraging puzzles intermittently generally suffices

What is the one-word answer to the riddle above?

---

**HINT 1:**

> Convoluted as it is, the riddle is not meaningless and describes the answer.

**HINT 2:**

> What could be another "word" for the acrostic clue?

**HINT 3:**

> The wordplay tag means a pun is necessary to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a guess:

> **BOREDOM**

Because:

> This satisfies the acrostic "Land of pigs" -> "boar - dom".
>
>  The riddle itself paints a picture of people who are bored at work/school, occasionally solving puzzles to relieve their boredom.

Comment: Hopefully, this puzzle was able to distract you from your boredom even if for only a while. Great job!

Answer (score 9):

How about:

> **GUINEA**

The words of the riddle form:

> An acrostic, spelling out **LAND OF PIGS**

I then reason that:

> A country (‘land’) whose name might fit this cryptic clue is Guinea, as in ‘Guinea pigs’.  Not sure right now how this might relate to the title though…

Comment: That was quick! Unfortunately, that is just one of the clues. Was thinking of adding the acrostics tag later as a hint but I guess it's too obvious for veterans like you.

Comment: @greysaff Ha! I love that you just called me a veteran :) Hmmm... 'Just one of the clues' - I'll have to think on this a little further then...